# TypeScript: Keys of object which values have specific type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm working on this kind of generic filter function (pardon all the compositional arguments)

It's purpose is to return me a matcher function, that compares given property `(propertyName: keyof T)` of an object `(item: T)` with a term `(term: string)`.

```
type Predicate<T> = (item: T) => boolean
type ConditionedPredicate<T, C> = (condition: C) => Predicate<T>

export const matchBy = <T>(propertyName: keyof T): ConditionedPredicate<T, string> => (term) => (item) => {
  const propertyValue = item[propertyName] as string
  const substringRegex = new RegExp(term, 'i')

  return Boolean(propertyValue.match(substringRegex))
}
```

The problem here, as you can see, is that I have to cast `propertyValue` to string.

**Question** How can I avoid that, defining the type for `propertyName` that allows any key of `T` that has type of `string`?

Answer (score 0):

In this code:

```js
type Predicate<T> = (item: T) => boolean;
type ConditionedPredicate<T, C> = (condition: C) => Predicate<T>;

export const matchBy = <T, K extends keyof T>(propertyName: K): ConditionedPredicate<T, string> => (term) => (item) => {
  const propertyValue = item[propertyName];
  const substringRegex = new RegExp(term, 'i');

  if (typeof propertyValue === 'string') {
    return Boolean(propertyValue.match(substringRegex));
  }

  return false;
};
```

typeScript will infer the correct type for `propertyValue`, and you don't need to explicitly cast it to string

Comment: Thanks, Alfonso. This was the first solution I tried, but it doesn't guarantee compilation-time type-safety. What I'm looking for is a code that will not allow me to pass keys that yield anything but string as value